# Cannot execute a simple maven project through jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I'm using Linux - Ubuntu 14.04.
I've installed Jenkins 2.7.2.

I created a maven project in Eclipse and followed the instructions provided in this link http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html.

After completing the project setup, I executed it as Maven Project and the build was successful.

Then I installed Jenkins, installed Maven Integration Plugin, created a Maven Project and added the Root POM location and in 'Goals and options' field, I gave 'test' as input and executed the Build, but the Build was a failure.

The console output is as follows:

```
Started by user QA Admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebDriverTest2
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 58065
[WebdriverTest] $ java -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.7.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.60.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 58065
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebdriverTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WebdriverTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WebdriverTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WebdriverTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ WebdriverTest ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, /home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml is 23 min old

    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:228)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:634)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoFailed(Maven3Builder.java:667)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoFailed(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.097 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-25T17:16:17+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/981M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project WebdriverTest: Error creating properties files for forking: No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/pom.xml to WebdriverTest/WebdriverTest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WebdriverTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebDriverTest2/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/; will archive in a separate pass
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have given an absolute path to the pom file.  At the top Maven logs

`Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebDriverTest2`

And at the end you can see

`/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebDriverTest2/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/; will archive in a separate pass`

So if what I'm thinking is correct, you just need to change the "Root POM" parameter.  Give it a relative path to the pom.xml from the project's root directory.  So if your project is

`WebDriverTest
  src/main/java
  src/test/java
  ...
  pom.xml`

The "Root POM" parameter should just be `pom.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my Root POM path "/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/pom.xml". I've added this in Jenkins config.

Comment: try only keep the WebdriverTest/pom.xml

Comment: It's looking for the pom at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebDriverTest2/home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/, which doesn't exist.  I'm used to running Jenkins in a continuous integration environment, so things might be different for me. Try changing your workspace to /home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/

Comment: I tried both the possibilities, when changed, 'No such file found' error is shown in Jenkins.

Comment: when you change the workspace to /home/admin/workspace/WebdriverTest/ , also you change the Root POM parameter to just "pom.xml". I'll have time to try to reproduce what you're doing later